# Redefine an environment such that it always has a certain optional value unless told otherwise

Tags: optional-arguments

How can I redefine an environment so that it will have a certain optional value unless told otherwise?

My particular problem is: how can I redefine the `itemize` environment so that its `beginpenalty` option is always set to `beginpenalty=10000`?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

List:

\begin{itemize}[beginpenalty=10000]
    \item Item
    \item Item
    \item Item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As you use enumitem, use its tools: `\setlist[itemize]{beginpenalty=10000}`

Comment: You could also wrap it (and have both versions available): `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{bpitemize}{%
O{beginpenalty=10000} +b}{%
\begin{itemize}[#1]
#2
\end{itemize}
}{}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

List:

\begin{bpitemize}
    \item Item
    \item Item
    \item Item
\end{bpitemize}

\end{document}`